# Disable cut and/or paste in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, macos, paste, cut

I'd like to disable cut and/or paste in the menubar at runtime, in my ObjC app. I know that that's possible in iOS using 
    -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)aSelector withSender:(id)sender

Is there anything similar for MacOS?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [NSUserInterfaceValidations Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSUserInterfaceValidations_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004183), a generic protocol for validating items. You simply implement the `validateUserInterfaceItem:` method and return NO to disable the action.

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id < NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem >)anItem {
    if([anItem action] == @selector(cut:) ||
       [anItem action] == @selector(copy:) ||
       [anItem action] == @selector(paste:)) return NO;
    return [self respondsToSelector:[anItem action]];
}
```

There is also a [NSMenuValidation Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004173http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004173), which performs the same function but is used only to validate menu items, instead of all interface items. If you don't implement it, the system will fall back to the standard validation instead.

Comment: Excuse me, where do I have to put this code? In the app delegate? I've never used this protocol so I don't know where to start. Do I have to "connect" the menu items to it some way? Thank you

Comment: They should be placed in whatever is accepting the action. This is usually the control containing the data, such as a text view, but can be a document or window controller. If you plan on having them always disabled, you could change the target to some other object so that you only need to add the methods to one object.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your availability. Second: let's say I want Cut/Paste always behave the standard way BUT when my NSImageView is the first responder. I know that I can make a NSImageView not editable at all, but I need to let it editable and having full control to the state (enabled/disabled) of Cut/Paste. I've already tried putting that code in the subclass implementation of my NSImageView, but it doesn't seem to work... Where am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps NSImageView implements `NSMenuValidation`, overriding your methods. However, NSImageView also has a `setAllowsCutCopyPaste:` method. Calling `[myImageView setAllowsCutCopyPaste:NO]` is all you need to do for this case.

Comment: As I said before, I'm aware of that method but it's not what I'm looking for since ti disables/enables cut, copy and paste all together but I need to keep copy enabled... I'm getting mad...

Comment: Try using the `validateMenuItem:` method from [NSMenuValidation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) instead. This will be the first method checked when the menu is brought up. Also make sure the menu is set to validate its items.